# StringTemplate check if array is empty in java

Tags: java, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

How to check using the StringTemplate if the array is not empty?

The example below doesn't work:

```
<if(teams.length > 0)>
  <ul>
    <teams:{team | <li><team></li> }>
  </ul>
<endif>
```

Other (not working) Exaple:

```
String content = "<if(teams)>list: <teams;separator=\", \"><endif>";
ST template = new ST(content);
template.add("teams", new Long[]{123L, 124L});

System.out.println(template.render());

System.out.println("--------");

content = "<if(teams)>list: <teams;separator=\", \"><endif>";
template = new ST(content);
template.add("teams", new Long[]{});

System.out.println(template.render());
```

Output:

```
list: 123, 124
--------
list:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use:

```
<if(teams)>
```

This condition will evaluate to false if the `teams` list is empty.
From the [StringTemplate](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST4/Templates#Templates-conditionals) documentation:

> The conditional expressions test of the presence or absence of an
>   attribute. Strict separation of model and view requires that
>   expressions cannot test attribute values such as name=="parrt". If you
>   do not set an attribute or pass in a null-valued attribute, that
>   attribute evaluates to false. StringTemplate also returns false for
>   empty lists and maps as well a "empty" iterators such as 0-length
>   lists (see Interpreter.testAttributeTrue()). All other attributes
>   evaluate to true with the exception of Boolean objects. Boolean
>   objects evaluate to their object value. Strictly speaking, this is a
>   violation of separation, but it's just too weird to have Boolean false
>   objects evaluate to true just because they are non-null.

Example:

```
String content = "1: <if(teams)>list: <teams;separator=\", \"><endif>";
ST template = new ST(content);

// Create a list with two items
List<Long> teams = new ArrayList<Long>();
teams.add(123L);
teams.add(124L);

template.add("teams", teams);

System.out.println(template.render());

// Add separator
System.out.println("--------");

content = "2: <if(teams)>list: <teams;separator=\", \"><endif>";
template = new ST(content);

// Create empty list
teams = new ArrayList<Long>();
template.add("teams", teams);

System.out.println(template.render());
```

Output:

```
1: list: 123, 124
--------
2:
```

Comment: @czerasz apologies, it evaluates to false if a list is empty, not array. can you store your array as a list?